# Delay array map iteration in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have this array, that I want to iterate. I need to delay it by a couple of seconds before the next.

```
{this.props.things.map((thing, index) => {
   return (
     <div key={index}>{thing.content}</div>
     // Delay 1 second here
   )
})}
```

The initial state of this array is always more than one. For UI purposes I want them to load in one by one in to the DOM.

Comment: why do you need delay in `.map`? could you clarify issue

Comment: Specify what you're trying to achieve at a reasonably high level, and why you have come to the conclusion that a delay is required?

Comment: The initial state of this array is always more than one. For UI purposes I want them to load in one by one on the initial render.

Comment: Why not animate them into view with CSS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The render function of react is synchronous. Also javascript map is synchronous. So using timers is not the right solution here.

You can however, in your component state, keep track of items that have been rendered and update that state using javascript timers:

For an example implementation check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o980s4oj/):

```
React.createClass({

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      renderedThings: [],
      itemsRendered: 0
    }
  },

  render() {
    // Render only the items in the renderedThings array
    return (
      <div>{
        this.state.renderedThings.map((thing, index) => (
          <div key={index}>{thing.content}</div>
        ))
      }</div>
    )
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    this.scheduleNextUpdate()
  },

  scheduleNextUpdate() {
    this.timer = setTimeout(this.updateRenderedThings, 1000)
  },

  updateRenderedThings() {
    const itemsRendered = this.state.itemsRendered
    const updatedState = {
      renderedThings: this.state.renderedThings.concat(this.props.things[this.state.itemsRendered]),
      itemsRendered: itemsRendered+1
    }
    this.setState(updatedState)
    if (updatedState.itemsRendered < this.props.things.length) {
      this.scheduleNextUpdate()
    }
  },

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.timer)
  }

})
```

Comment: Solid solution. Works great. Thanks.